# PHP PDO SQLite UPDATE is not saved in file

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have this PHP 5.6.29 code snippet:

```
$QsoId = $SQLiteData["QsoId"];
$SQLiteData["MyAntenna"] = $ODBCAnt;
$query = sprintf("UPDATE Log SET 'MyAntenna' = ':%s' WHERE 'QsoId' = %s", $ODBCAnt, $QsoId);
$qry = $SQLite["connection"]->prepare($query);                    
$res = $qry->execute();
$tt = $qry->rowCount();
```

This works as expected and $res is set to TRUE.  The problem is apparently nothing changes in the data file. According to what I read, a 'COMMIT' is not required in PDO.  $tt is set to 0.

Comment: And what is `$tt`?

Comment: $tt is supposed to be a check to see how many rows were affected by UPDATE query.

Comment: And what is *the value of* `$tt`?

Comment: $tt now equals 1 which is what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.  A brain fog had settled in and all that needed to be done was to unquote the field names.  Thanks all.